# Implementing a full page animated loader

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a ripple full page loader. I'm trying to create the one like [here](https://templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_558_klassy_cafe/).
I want the code to be simple with no plugins ideally.
I can load the page preloader but am wondering how I get the loading page to disappear once the main page has loaded? The page just will not fade! Have researched and tried all sorts of methods.
This is the code so far:

```js
// Page loading animation
$(window).on('load', function() {
  if ($('.cover').length) {
    $('.cover').parallax({
      imageSrc: $('.cover').data('image'),
      zIndex: '1'
    });
  }

  $("#preloader").animate({
    'opacity': '0'
  }, 600, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#preloader").css("visibility", "hidden").fadeOut();
    }, 300);
  });
});
```

```css
#preloader {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fb5849;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  color: #fff;
}

#preloader .jumper {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#preloader .jumper>div {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-animation: jumper 1s 0s linear infinite;
  animation: jumper 1s 0s linear infinite;
}

#preloader .jumper>div:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.33333s;
  animation-delay: 0.33333s;
}

#preloader .jumper>div:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.66666s;
  animation-delay: 0.66666s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes jumper {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes jumper {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="preloader">
  <div class="jumper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as below, using vanilla JavaScript. You can adapt it for jQuery. Also you can remove that `setTimout`, added just for testing purpose.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("preloader").classList.add("hide");
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#preloader {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fb5849;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

#preloader.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#preloader .jumper {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#preloader .jumper > div {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-animation: jumper 1s 0s linear infinite;
  animation: jumper 1s 0s linear infinite;
}

#preloader .jumper > div:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.33333s;
  animation-delay: 0.33333s;
}

#preloader .jumper > div:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.66666s;
  animation-delay: 0.66666s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes jumper {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes jumper {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="preloader">
  <div class="jumper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah finally-Thank you!!Code works a treat. Am eternally greatful!:)